# Is there a search limit for Eclipse Maven plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I can use Eclipse Maven plugin to search artifact for dependencies.
When I click "org.apache.ant", I'll see library in "org.apache.ant.*".
But if I click "org.apache" only, it shows nothing.

I'm not sure the reason, is it a limit? I use Eclipse 4.3 64bit with m2e 1.4

Answer (score 0):

I believe the limit is 2^16 => 65K

Comment: Can you back that up with some valid sources?